# Facing problems in merging multiple Pdf files using PDFBox

Tags: pdfbox

I am trying to merge six pdf files. In the merged document, I am seeing
some boxes in place of text.
Text got replaced by boxes and images got lost.

Please let me know what is wrong with the code and how can we resolve
this issue.

```
public static void main (String args[])
{
    String[] docletNamesAsPdf = { "RP_OverviewPart1.pdf", "RP_OverviewPart2.pdf", "RP_OverviewPart3.pdf", "RP_OverviewPart4.pdf", "RP_OverviewPart5.pdf", "RP_OverviewPart6.pdf" };

    PDDocument dest = PDDocument.load(docletNamesAsPdf[0]);
    PDDocument src = PDDocument.load(docletNamesAsPdf[1]);
    dest = mergePdfs(dest, src);

    for (int i = 2; i < docletNamesAsPdf.length; i++)
    {
         src = PDDocument.load(docletNamesAsPdf[i]);
         dest = pptToPdf.mergePdfs(dest, src);
    }

    try {
        dest.save("MergedDoc.pdf");
    } catch (COSVisitorException e) {
        ;
    }
    src.close();
    dest.close();
}

public PDDocument mergePdfs(PDDocument dest, PDDocument src) throws IOException {
    new PDFMergerUtility().appendDocument(dest, src);
    return dest;
}
```

Thanks 
Manisha Sharma

Comment: Furthermore please indicate what this `pptToPdf` member is and which library version you use.

Comment: And try the command line version first, with the -nonSeq parameter https://pdfbox.apache.org/1.8/commandline.html#pdfMerger

Comment: Your first call of a `mergePdfs` in your `main` does not call the method you provided below because `main` is static and `mergePdfs` is not. The following `mergePdfs` calls in the loop call a method of that name of some `pptToPdf` object. Is that object a direct instance of the class you extracted your code from? If not, these calls may also call other methods than the one you provided below.

Comment: Your question was answered in PDFBOX-2638. I suggest you answer the question yourself here (after you get it to work) and use the code by Maruan, and also mention the remarks by Andreas. (I could do it myself, but I didn't really do any work here, so maybe that wouldn't be fair)